# Projection of a space curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry, plane-curves

Let $C= V(F, H) \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ be a reduced space curve  defined by homogeneous polynomials $F, H$ and $p: \mathbb{P}^3 \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$ a rational projection from a general point $Q \in \mathbb{P}^3$. As $Q$ we assumed to be general, $p_*C \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ is a (reduced) plane curve $\subset \mathbb{P}^2$.

If we know the explicit equation for $F(x,y,z,w)$ and $H(x,y,z,w) \in K[x,y,z,w]$, can we also write down an explicit homogeneous polynomial $G \in K[x,y,z]$ which defines $p_*C$ dependent on $F$ & $H$ ?

Comment: A homogeneous polynomial $F\in k[x,y,z,w]$ defines a surface in $\Bbb P^3$, not a curve.

Comment: ohhh yes sorry, you are of course right. I update it in a few minutes

Comment: Look up resultant of two polynomials.

Comment: yes, so in the case $=Q=[0:0:0:1]$ the answer is $R(F,H)$ where we consider $F,H$ as polynomials with coeficients in $K[x,y,z]$ in undeterminant $w$. otherwise we do a linear transform